Why are these results different between two types code of Java?
First of all, my mother language is not English.
Now I study Increment(++) ande Decrement(--) operators of Java.
I tried an issue. But the result of mu code differents from my expectation.
Issue

Assign an integer to x.
Using Increment(++) ande Decrement(--) operators and showing x.

My code
I wrotea code like this ;
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int x = 19;
        int inc = x++;
        int dec = x--;

        System.out.println(inc);
        System.out.println(dec);

    }
}

My Expectation
I expected the result will be "20" and "19".
Result
However, running result was "19" and "20".
I still can't understand why the result was "19" and "20".
The thing I want to know

Why the result of running my code was "19" and "20".
If the result of running my code will be "20" and "19", where should I fix my code?


Interesting. Usually beginner learning ++ and -- don't care about the return value because the main purpose of ++ and -- is to change the value of x. Most of the time you want to use x again after x++ or x--. The return value of ++ and -- is used only when later you find out those can be used to simplify the code in some fancy way in some specific situation. If you don't want/care changing the value of x, you better just use x+1 and x-1.

So actually x++ and x-- returns x and then increment x by 1.
If you want to firstly increase value by 1 and only then return a value you can use ++x and --x:
int x = 19;
int inc = ++x;
int dec = --x;

System.out.println(inc);
System.out.println(dec);


When you are using the x++ you are doing a postincrement which means the variable value (in your case x's value) is used first and then incremented after the expression. When you are using the ++x you are doing a preincrement which means the variable value is incremented and uses the new value inc in the expression.
so use preincrement for both and the output shall look like your expectations.
